# Sequelize, get id after findOrCreate

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, unique

I try to create an associated table of tags with id of tag and id of related article, so first i do a findOrCreate tag, this function is operational and works perfectly, but when i do a then(function(result){}) and with the result i create my association with the id of the tag like result.id the id returned is null ! So in the case where i do a simple create it returns me an id, but when i do a findOrCreate the id is null !! What can i do to get the id of my created entry with findOrCreate function ? if there's another solution to create an entry that not already existing i'm also interested....here's my function in app.js

```
 function(sales, callback) {
      if(req.body.tags) {
            tagsArray = req.body.tags.split(',');
            var obj = tagsArray.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
                          acc[i] = cur;
                          return acc;
                        }, {});

            callback(null, async.forEachOf(obj, (value,key,callback) => {
                tagsFormattedArray.push({tags: value})
                tagsController.create(req, res, value).then(function(result){
                        callback(null, tagSpottingController.create(req, res, result.id, idCreation))
                     })
            }))
      } 
 }
```

here's my tag controller :

```
module.exports = {
    create(req, res, tag) {
        return Tags
          .findOrCreate({
            where: {
            name: tag
         },
        defaults: { 
           name: tag
        }
   })
 }
};
```

here is my tag model :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Tags = sequelize.define('Tags', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
        },

        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'createdAt'
         },

        updatedAt: {
           type: DataTypes.DATE,
           field: 'updatedAt'
      }},{
        timestamps: true

    });

  return Tags;
}
```

I read the doc and i tested to do this in my tag controller :

```
module.exports = {
    findOrCreate(req, res, tag) {
        return Tags
          .findOrCreate({
            where: {
              name: tag
           },
           defaults: { 
             name: tag
           }
     }).spread((tags, created) => {
       console.log(tags.get({
          plain: true
       }))
  })
 }
};
```

It console log all my created tags (the ones who are not in the db) that the behaviour that i wanted !...but when i try to do a return instead of a console log , to get my ids, it returns me only the false result (the one which already exists in the db)...there something that i don't understand

Comment: Could you please format your code a bit. And also provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: i've edit my post

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we cannot directly return the result of the spread so i had to push it inside a callback. Here my final code :

```
  tagsController.findOrCreate(req, res, value).spread(function(tags, created){
                    if (created){
                        callback(null, tagSpottingController.create(req, res, tags.id, idCreation))
                    }
                    else {
                        callback(null, tagSpottingController.create(req, res, tags.id, idCreation))
                    }  
                 })
```